# Apache Synapse custom Mediator to execute system command

Tags: apache, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I create a custom mediator in apache synapse to invoke some system command such as java -jar, execute shell script, etc.. But i have no luck to this, i tried these codes :

Process process =runtime.exec("touch /opt/FILE.txt");

and

Process p = runtime.exec(new String[]{"java","-jar","/opt/MyMediator.jar"});

both of them were runnable when i create the jar and run the jar manually, but when i deploy it to the synapse lib, it wont work. So can anybody tell me how to do this properly?

Thanks,

Comment: how does your synapse sequence look like where you call the custom mediator?

Comment: @FiveO..My Synapse sequence look like this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Service01"
       transports="vfs"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="enable"
       statistics="enable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
   <class name="com.exec.RunExe"></class>  
         <send/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>